# How to get json from ajax to python

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask, request

I have a problem that I do not know how to get the data ajax sends to me.

Here is html with ajax:

```
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="pass"/>
        <span id="btn">send</span>
    </form>
    <script>
        function log() {
            var email, pass;
            email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
            fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
                body: {
                    email: email,
                    password: pass
                },
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-Type': 'aplication/json'
                },
                method: 'post'
            }).then(response => response.json(), err => {throw err}).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
        }
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        btn.addEventListener('click', log);
    </script>
```

Here is Python code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
    def login():
        print(request.get_json()) #i dont know how to get data here 
        return json.dumps({"success":True})
```

That is code only for test to get json.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `body` option to JSON:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: pass
}),
```

Comment: but when i post data with this 

`body: JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: pass
}),`
and get this with 

`request.get_json()`

still receives None

Comment: You have a typo: `'aplication/json'` there's two p's in `application`.

Comment: You can use `request.get_json(force=True)` and it will ignore the `Content-type` header.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

With `jquery`, you can create a `data` object, the values of which can be accessed in the body of the specified route:

```
<html> 
  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="pass"/>
    <button type='button' id='submit'>Submit</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#submit').click(function(){
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#pass').val();
        $.ajax({
         url: "/login",
         type: "get",
         data: {email: email, pass:password},
         success: function(response) {
          if(response.status){
            //do something if successful
          }
          else{
           //do something if login fails
          }
        },
         error: function(xhr) {
           //Do Something to handle error
       }
     });
     });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

In your `flask app`:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
  email = flask.request.args.get('email')
  password = flask.request.args.get('pass')
  return flask.jsonify({'status':isvalid(email, password)})
```

Comment: but i want do it with post, thats the point